# How to make the Collapse position to bottom-right after clicking on expand icon in AntD

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using AntD Collapse for displaying a list of items after expand icon is clicked.

I want the position of expandIcon to go to bottom-right after all the list of the data when expand icon is clicked (just like in google news), but found only two options (left|right) for 'expandIconPosition', no option for top or bottom.
How can we align the expandIcon to bottom-right, when expand icon is clicked?

Few lines from the code for reference:

```
<Collapse
    ghost
    style={{ marginTop: "-1vh" }}
    expandIcon={({ isActive }) => (
      <DownOutlined
        style={{ marginTop: "-2vh" }}
        rotate={isActive ? 180 : 0}
      />
    )}
    expandIconPosition="right"
>
    <Panel>
        <div>
            {list()}  //list of items
        </div>
    </Panel>
</Collapse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution. Make `Collapse` a **controlled** component by specifying `activeKey` prop and then the value of it will be based on state. Then, by tracking the `activeKeys` state you can now do a conditional rendering (hide and show) on icons:

```
const [activePanelKeys, setActivePanelKeys] = useState([]);


const handlePanelIconClick = (panelKey, makeActive) => {
  if (makeActive) {
    setActivePanelKeys([...activePanelKeys, panelKey]);
  } else {
    setActivePanelKeys(activePanelKeys.filter((aPK) => aPK !== panelKey));
  }
};

<Collapse
    activeKey={activePanelKeys}
    expandIconPosition="right"
    expandIcon={() => <DownOutlined />}
    // expandIcon={(panelProps) => (
    //   <DownOutlined
    //     onClick={() => handlePanelIconClick(panelProps.panelKey, true)}
    //   />
    // )}
    onChange={e => setActivePanelKeys(e)} //if you want to click only icon, comment this and uncomment the above expandedIcon
>
    <Panel
        header="This is panel header 1"
        key="p1"
        showArrow={activePanelKeys.indexOf("p1") === -1}
    >
        <div>{text}</div>
        {activePanelKeys.indexOf("p1") !== -1 && (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "right", marginTop: 10 }}>
                <UpOutlined onClick={() => handlePanelIconClick("p1", false)} />
            </div>
        )}
    </Panel>

    {/* <PanelContent header="This is panel header 2" key="p2">
      {text}
    </PanelContent> */}

</Collapse>;
```

Here is the complete sample code:

[image: Edit]

*Note:* I tried to make a reusable `Panel` component but it seems that the reveal animation were gone. You can uncomment the commented `PanelContent` on the code to see the difference.

Hope that I hit what you want.